# Equations for inverted pendulum with a fixed base?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, oscillators

I'm researching how to control an [inverted pendulum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_pendulum) with a fixed base, using an actuated mass at the head of the pendulum to shift the center of mass in reaction to the tilt. I'm trying to research prior art, but Googling for "inverted pendulum fixed base" find me a ton of research on equations for the problem of an inverted pendulum mounted on a cart. I doubt I'm the first person to research the fixed-base form, so I assume I'm either using the wrong search terms or the task itself is infeasible. Is it possible to control an inverted pendulum without a moving cart? If so, where would I find the equations describing its motion?

Comment: You may want to check out [Kapitza's pendulum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kapitza%27s_pendulum).

Comment: @sammygerbil, I'm sorry my description was not more clear. Yes, that's essentially what I'm asking. If you have a mass at the head that can shift along the horizontal axis, can this be used to keep the pendulum upright? As a very rough example, imagine your body (standing perfectly straight, on the balls of your feet) was the pendulum, with your head as the mass. If you started to fall forwards or backwards, could you correct your orientation by leaning your head in the opposite direction?

Comment: @sammygerbil I think the more formal term for the model I'm describing is the ["cart-table"](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/An-example-of-cart-table-model9_fig1_224373479) version of the inverted pendulum.